# How do I find out where a bitcoin address is from?

Tags: address, security

I am not looking necessarily a name but more like is it an offline, coinbase, blockchain.com, etc...

I had $80 sent from my account yesterday and it says it went to `1H8KZWdTeRuiCq4NyCTYGA8Uw9XjKuLPCx` however I don't remember this or know this address. I know that this doesn't sound like a lot of money but for me it is. Please help me if you can

Answer (score 1):

> **How do I find out where a bitcoin address is from?**

You can't find a person, organisation or place from a Bitcoin address alone.

A Bitcoin address isn't really an address in the normal sense. It doesn't label a place or person or anything else in the real world. Really its just a reference number produced from a secret number by a mathematical function. You can't even reverse the maths to find the secret number from the address.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not remember making this transaction, your keys or devices may have been compromised.

It is not possible to determine who or what entity holds the private keys to a bitcoin address - bitcoin is anonymous by design. Although there are techniques to link addresses to known parties such as exchanges, they are rarely 100% accurate, and usually cost money to look up an address.

In any case, it would not help you here, since the address mentioned has only one incoming transaction, and no outgoing transactions (yet), which means there is no pattern that could potentially help identify the operator.

You should assume you are compromised and reset passwords on all devices, accounts, and wipe any devices that may have had access to that account.